# how to add number along the axis when creating a grid

Tags: java

So basically I have made this grid for my battleships game, however, the axis is no numbered and although this is not a massive problem, It would just make it look better and be a good thing to have?

So basically does anyone know what I need to add into the following code to make me be able to have numbers along the axis?

it would be from 1-6 
Thanks.

```
public static void creategrid(String[][] grid)
      {
         for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
         {
            for(int column = 0; column < grid[0].length; column++)
            {
               grid[row][column] = "-";
            }
         }
      }


public static void showgrid(String[][] grid)
      {

         for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
         {
            if(DEBUG == true)
            {
               for(int column = 0; column < grid[0].length; column++)
               {
                  System.out.print(" "+grid[row][column]);
              }
              System.out.println("");
            }
            else
            {
               for(int column = 0; column < grid[0].length; column++)
               {
                  if(grid[row][column].equals("S") || (grid[row][column].equals("D") || (grid[row][column].equals("B")) ))
                  {
                     System.out.print(" "+"-");
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                     System.out.print(" "+grid[row][column]);
                  }
                }
               System.out.println("");
            }
         }

  }
```

Comment: Your grid is formed with the one character, however numbers can have multiple characters. Do you have a plan to handle that?

Comment: printf is important for making sure that all the characters fit correctly.

Comment: no to sure what you mean, I was just looking for a simple way to do it if that exists